# How to create delay between two timers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.timers.timer

### **GOAL**

Have two methods : Add() and Remove().

- Add() method occurs every X seconds until it is stopped by user; Adds
  object to DB; Waits for N seconds; calls Remove();
- Remove() method is called by Add() method and removes object added by
  Add() method.

**My Code**

```
        static bool keepGoing = true;

        static System.Timers.Timer AddMethodTimer= new System.Timers.Timer();
        static System.Timers.Timer RemoveMethodTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        private static void Execute()
        {
            if (!keepGoing)
            {
                AddMethodTimer.Stop();
                RemoveMethodTimer.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                AddMethodTimer.Interval = 30; // X = 30
                RemoveMethodTimer.Interval = 5; // N = 5

                AddMethodTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Add);
                AddMethodTimer.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(RemoveMethodTimer.Interval)//In this case, N=5; 
                RemoveMethodTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Remove); 
            }
        }
        private static void Add(object source, ElapseEventArgs e)
        {
             //add operation
        }
        private static void Remove(object source, ElapseEventArgs e)
        {
            //remove operation
        }
```

User can only change "keepGoing" variable. If it is false, timer should stop. This whole code is triggered on change(I have a post IActionResult which handles it. It works fine. When keepGoing is changed, it enters the code I provided).

**NOTE** : If object is inserted to DB and user makes keepGoing false, Remove() will not be executed

Comment: Reuse the same timer, set the interval on the elapsed event of the first. Even better would be using async. `await Task.Delay(30); AddMethodTimer(); await Task.Delay(5); RemoveMethodTimer()`

Comment: @Fildor my bad will edit it. First "Add" is called Execute

Comment: 1 Question: What if object is inserted into DB but not yet deleted and just now user switches "keepGoing" to false. Shall 1. `Remove` be executed as scheduled? 2. `Remove` be executed immediatly? or 3. `Remove` not be executed at all?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You mean like this? : Added this in Add() method  `await 
                Task.Delay(30); 
                AddMethodTimer.Start(); 
                await Task.Delay(5);

                RemoveMethodTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Remove);'
                RemoveMethodTimer.Start();`

Comment: You don't need the timers if you are going async.

Comment: @Fildor Remove will not be executed.

Comment: "Remove will not be executed" - that is an important requirement that you should add to your question.

Comment: @Fildor WIll do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with timer, I'd suggest something like this:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer myTimer = null;
private static readonly syncObj = new object();

public static bool Execute( bool runTimer )
{
     if(runTimer)
     {
         lock(syncObj) // myTimer access shall be thread safe
         {
             if(myTimer != null) return false;
             // Timer is not active => activate
             myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
             myTimer.AutoReset = false; // 1-Time trigger!!
             myTimer.Elapsed += AddOnTimer;
             myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds; // Interval is in ms!
             myTimer.Enabled = true;
         }
     }
     else
     {
        lock(syncObj)
        {
            if( myTimer == null ) return false;
            myTimer.Enabled = false;
            myTimer.Dispose();
            myTimer = null;
        }
     }
     return true;
}

private static void AddOnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    AddObjToDB();
    lock( syncObj )
    {
      if( myTimer == null ) return; // myTimer has been canceled, meanwhile
      myTimer.Elapsed -= AddOnTimer;    // Instead of Add, next time
      myTimer.Elapsed += RemoveOnTimer; // execute Remove
      myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;            
      myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private static void RemoveOnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RemoveObjFromDB();
    lock( syncObj )
    {
      if( myTimer == null ) return; // myTimer has been canceled
      myTimer.Elapsed -= RemoveOnTimer;  // Instead of Remove, next time
      myTimer.Elapsed += AddOnTimer;     // execute Add
      myTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds;
      myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Async approach:

```
public static async Task Execute( CancellationToken cancel )
{
    while( !cancel.IsCancellationRequested )
    {
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cancel);
      await AddObjToDBAsync(cancel);
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancel);
      await RemoveFromDBAsync(cancel);
    }
}

private static async Task AddObjToDBAsync( CancellationToken cancel )
{ 
   if( !cancel.IsCancellationRequested )
   {
       await YourDataLayer.AddAsync( someObj ); // <= I made this up, of course. "Async all the way" is recommended.
   }
}

private static async Task RemoveObjFromDBAsync( CancellationToken cancel )
{ 
   if( !cancel.IsCancellationRequested )
   {
       await YourDataLayer.RemoveAsync( someObj );
   }
}
```

*( I just saw, Jeroen already posted an async approach. I'll leave it here, anyway. )

Comment: Tried timer approach. Starting and stopping work fine. Problem is that when timer is started, it adds objects several times in couple of seconds instead of once in every 30 seconds. I am calling it from Post IActionResult like this                 `NewTimerApproach.SetActive(true);`

Comment: Fixed it. @Greg Interval is in Milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you! If anyone is interested, I tried Jeroen's async approach too. It worked but froze the screen and preferred timers.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the async way. This doesn't 'use' timers in your code. By using a CancellationTokenSource, you are able to cancel the Task.Delays as well.

This is for example. You should improve it, because if you cancel it within the 30 seconds delay, it will still call Add and Remove. You could use `if (!tcs.IsCancellationRequested) Add();` for that. Just play with it.

```
static CancellationTokenSource tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();

private static async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    while (!tcs.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(30000, tcs.Token);

        Add();

        await Task.Delay(5000, tcs.Token);

        Remove();
    }
}

private static void Stop()
{
    tcs.Cancel();
}

private static void Add()
{
    //add operation
}

private static void Remove()
{
    //remove operation
}
```